# Flutter how to delete field from firebase array

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to delete a field from my firebase array. I am using this code but it deletes then whole activity array.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                  .collection(
                                                      widget.user.user.uid)
                                                  .doc(documentName)
                                                  .update({
                                                "activities":
                                                    FieldValue.delete()
```

[image]

Instead I want to delete a specific field from 'activities' like activities[2]. How can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item at a specific index you can use the [arrayRemove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayRemove(java.lang.Object...)) method from [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayRemove(java.lang.Object...))

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.user.user.uid).doc(documentName).update({
"activities": FieldValue.arrayRemove("itemToRemove")
})
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work. I just want to delete the marked field. Should I replace "itemToRemove" from your code?

Comment: You should replace "itemToRemove" with the item you wish to remove from the array. As an example you might use the object {days: ["1","2",3",...}

Comment: Okay I have tried but I can’t get it work. Maybe because activities contains different file types.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `FieldValue.arrayRemove()` method and then pass the value that you want to remove using this :

```
var val=[];   //blank list for add elements which you want to delete
val.add('$addDeletedElements');

FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection(
  widget.user.user.uid)
  .doc(documentName)
  .update({
    "activities":
    FieldValue.arrayRemove(val])
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work. I just want to delete the marked field. Should I replace "val" from your code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell firebase full path like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("chat_dialog")
    .doc("India")
    .collection("dialog_details")
    .where(['firestore_id'].contains('your_value'))
    .get()
    .then((value) {
   
   

  print(value.docs.length);
  for (var element in value.docs) {
    print(element.id);
    
  }
});
```